# Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP - Flow error property `TIMESTAMP` (Property not found in object literal)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flowtype

I keep getting the error

> [flow] property `TIMESTAMP` (Property not found in object literal)

on the following block of code:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`${Config.ROOT}/transactions/${parentId}/`)
  .push({
    credits,
    date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ'),
    serverTimestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,   // <- here
    params: {
      value: euros,
    },
    type: 'topUp',
    details: transactionStatus,
  })
```

However, if I hover my mouse over the ServerValue property, even the lint config in my browser confirms that the property TIMESTAMP exists in ServerValue.

[image: ServerValue property]

What am I missing to make flow accept this block of code?

Comment: What is flow? The flow tag is described as: _"This is a meta tag and should not be used."_ Maybe you can find a more appropriate tag for your question.

Comment: And shouldn't it be simply `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` instead of `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Flow is static type checker for javascript - https://flow.org/

Comment: Deleted (and then undeleted) my answer since it might be wrong. Want to throw up a repro-repo? Otherwise it's a pain to check what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but flow seems to be interpreting the ServerValue as a [union type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/). The message says that the ServerValue has two possibilities:

```
{
    TIMESTAMP: any | {}
}
```

or

```
{} //Empty
```

So TIMESTAMP may or may not exist. You probably need to throw an existence check around it. Maybe something like:

```
const {TIMESTAMP} = firebase.database.ServerValue
if (TIMESTAMP != null) {
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`${Config.ROOT}/transactions/${parentId}/`)
    .push({
    credits,
    date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ'),
    serverTimestamp: TIMESTAMP, // No longer null
    params: {
      value: euros,
    },
    type: 'topUp',
    details: transactionStatus,
  })
} else {
  throw new Error("Missing TIMESTAMP");
}
```

Comment: You're right, the flow type definition of ServerValue is : ` { TIMESTAMP: any | {} } | {} ` so TIMESTAMP may not exist. As you suggested I get the same flow error in `const {TIMESTAMP} = firebase.database.ServerValue`. I have to verify first with `if (firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP != null) {
      const TS = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP   ...`

Comment: One more thing, inside the `if (firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP != null) {`, if I get the value with `const {TIMESTAMP} = firebase.database.ServerValue`I get the same flow error `[flow] property `TIMESTAMP` (Property not found in object literal)`. However, if I do it like this: `const TS = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAM` flow does not show any error. Why is that?

Comment: Interesting fact. If instead of `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP != null ` I do `if (firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP) { const {TIMESTAMP} = firebase.database.ServerValue`, then there are no erros.

Comment: @FranciscoSarmento Re: your question: Not sure, I'd probably have to check it locally to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase database TIMESTAMP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue) is documented as a non-null object, and this seems inconsistent with flows understanding, as `any` would include null (what would the point of `any | {}` as `any` would include an object?).

I'd look into where flow is getting its types for firebase, is it using the firebase code in `node_modules` or is the project using flow-typed, or your own definitions?  The definition shown at the top of the screenshot seems correct, but not the one at the bottom.  I don't recognise your linter UI to be able to advise on why that might be.

Also, does the code actually work?  If necessary, you might be able to use a `$FlowFixMe` comment to suppress the error if its erroneous.

I'd avoid using a type refinement, as it doesn't document that you are using it to suppress an incorrect flow type annotation.

Here's how you could use `$FlowFixMe`:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`${Config.ROOT}/transactions/${parentId}/`)
  .push({
    credits,
    date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ'),
    // $FlowFixMe: TIMESTAMP incorrectly defined as potentially null
    serverTimestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    params: {
      value: euros,
    },
    type: 'topUp',
    details: transactionStatus,
  })
```

Comment: I am not using flow-typed, this definition is from the 'react-native-firebase' library. As according to the firebase documentation TIMESTAMP is always non-null, I will go with your solution of using // $FlowFixMe. Thanks for the tip!